# Configure Timeout in Apache 2.2 Server

Tags: configuration, server, timeout, httpd.conf, apache2.2

I tried to set timeout for my application in `httpd.conf` file to `1200` seconds. But it seems to timeout after `300` seconds.

This is how it is in my `httpd.conf` and I have made it available globally and outside `<VirtualHost>`

```
Timeout 1200
```

I also made the same change in `httpd-default.conf` file. Is/Are there any other way(s) I can configure the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application, since Apache was the load balancer and Weblogic was my server, I had to add/modify this change in `httpd.conf` file

```
WLIOTimeoutSecs 1200
```

This change worked for me.